# use custom icon in "react-rating" when fraction is greater that 1

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, react-rating

I am using the `react-rating` package in my Nextjs application and I want to use a custom icon both for the `emptySymbol` and `fullSymbol` of the Rating component.

The problem is when the rating is a decimal value like 3.7, the custom icon does not show up correctly.

```
   <Rating
      start={0}
      stop={5}
      step={1}
      direction="ltr"
      readonly={true}
      initialRating={3.7}
      emptySymbol={
        <Image src={"/assets/empty-star.svg"} width={16} height={16} alt="" />
      }
      fullSymbol={
        <Image src={"/assets/full-star.svg"} width={16} height={16} alt="" />
      }
      fractions={10}
   />
```

And the outcome is the picture below:

[image]

It seems that `react-rating` make the custom icon smaller instead of filling portion of it.

What I want to achieve is the same behavior as the default icons have: (below picture)

[image]

Comment: It looks like it might be setting a width on the icon to represent the partial value, perhaps try wrapping each of your `<Image />` components in e.g. a `<div>` with overflow hidden. If you can provide a reproducing example of the problem, it's more likely people will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DBS 's comment which somehow led me to the answer.

I am also using tailwindcss in my project. so the style `max-width: 100%;` was being overridden by `@tailwind base;` which led to this incorrect display of the "half-filled star".

And also for this specific situation, i used HTML native  tag instead of the Nextjs `Image` component.

The final solution was:

```
<div className="Custom-rating">
    <Rating
       start={0}
       stop={5}
       step={1}
       direction="ltr"
       readonly={true}
       initialRating={3.7}
       emptySymbol={
          <img src={"/assets/empty-star.svg"} width={16} height={16} alt="" />
       }
       fullSymbol={
          <img src={"/assets/full-star.svg"} width={16} height={16} alt="" />
       }
       fractions={10}
    />
</div>
```

And global.css file:

```
.Custom-rating img {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `flex-shrink: 0` to the icon did the trick for me

```
 <Rating
  icon={
    <WishlistFilledIcon
      style={{ flexShrink: 0 }}
      height={remSize}
      width={remSize}
    />
  }
  emptyIcon={
    <WishlistIcon
      style={{ flexShrink: 0 }}
      height={remSize}
      width={remSize}
    />
  }
/>
```